# How to split the elements of list into specific number of columns in Spark Scala?

Tags: arrays, scala, list, apache-spark, split

I have list containing random number of elements

Emp list

101 [a,b,c,d,e]

102 [q,w,e]

103 [z,x,w,t,e,q,s]

I need the result to be split between 3 columns

Emp  col1 col2 col3

101  a    b    c

101  d    e

102  q    w    e

103  z    x    w

103  t    e    q

103  s

Comment: Hi @rad, welcome to **StackOverflow**, you may take a look to [_"how to ask"_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve this and future questions. Specially you should provide some [_"research effort"_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and/or some code, to prove you already tried to solve the problem by yourself. Also, could you edit your question to make it more clear, using appropriate formatting.

Comment: Look at sliding or grouped. Scala has many things which can be used as a starting point.

Comment: Still needing help?

Comment: yes need some help. The number of elements in the list will be dynamic.

Comment: OK, will look at post soon

Comment: ok.. Thank you.

Comment: Actually, why it got a -x I am not sure as it is a good question. I am not able to solve foolproof actually.

Comment: Good posting already will leave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

```
scala> val df = Seq((101,Array("a","b","c","d","e")),(102,Array("q","w","e")),(103,Array("z","x","w","t","e","q","s"))).toDF("emp","list")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [emp: int, list: array<string>]

scala> df.show(false)
+---+---------------------+
|emp|list                 |
+---+---------------------+
|101|[a, b, c, d, e]      |
|102|[q, w, e]            |
|103|[z, x, w, t, e, q, s]|
+---+---------------------+


scala> val udf_slice = udf( (x:Seq[String]) => x.grouped(3).toList  )
udf_slice: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,ArrayType(ArrayType(StringType,true),true),Some(List(ArrayType(StringType,true))))

scala> df.select(col("*"), explode(udf_slice($"list")).as("newlist")).select($"emp", $"newlist"(0).as("col1"), $"newlist"(1).as("col2"), $"newlist"(2).as("col3") ).show(false)
+---+----+----+----+
|emp|col1|col2|col3|
+---+----+----+----+
|101|a   |b   |c   |
|101|d   |e   |null|
|102|q   |w   |e   |
|103|z   |x   |w   |
|103|t   |e   |q   |
|103|s   |null|null|
+---+----+----+----+


scala>
```

Spark **2.4** - just tried to implement without udfs.. but the slice() function is not accepting other columns as parameters for the range

```
val df = Seq((101,Array("a","b","c","d","e")),(102,Array("q","w","e")),(103,Array("z","x","w","t","e","q","s"))).toDF("emp","list")
df.show(false)
val df2 = df.withColumn("list_size_arr",  array_repeat(lit(1), ceil(size('list)/3).cast("int")) )
val df3 = df2.select(col("*"),posexplode('list_size_arr))
val udf_slice = udf( (x:Seq[String],start:Int, end:Int )  => x.slice(start,end) )
df3.withColumn("newlist",udf_slice('list,'pos*3, ('pos+1)*3  )).select($"emp", $"newlist").show(false)
```

Results:

```
+---+---------------------+
|emp|list                 |
+---+---------------------+
|101|[a, b, c, d, e]      |
|102|[q, w, e]            |
|103|[z, x, w, t, e, q, s]|
+---+---------------------+

+---+---------+
|emp|newlist  |
+---+---------+
|101|[a, b, c]|
|101|[d, e]   |
|102|[q, w, e]|
|103|[z, x, w]|
|103|[t, e, q]|
|103|[s]      |
+---+---------+
```

To get in separate columns

```
val df4 = df3.withColumn("newlist",udf_slice('list,'pos*3, ('pos+1)*3  )).select($"emp", $"newlist")
df4.select($"emp", $"newlist"(0).as("col1"), $"newlist"(1).as("col2"), $"newlist"(2).as("col3") ).show(false)


+---+----+----+----+
|emp|col1|col2|col3|
+---+----+----+----+
|101|a   |b   |c   |
|101|d   |e   |null|
|102|q   |w   |e   |
|103|z   |x   |w   |
|103|t   |e   |q   |
|103|s   |null|null|
+---+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Thank you.. This helped a lot:)

Comment: glad that it helped you.. please consider accepting the answer!

Comment: So, I am curious here. I tried this: val df2 = df.withColumn("v_List", expr("$v.toList.grouped(3)")) and it did not work. Look at the methods etc. I think I get it. You need to use a UDF for a list or array col part of a data frame. Is the performance of the UDF an issue you think? I solved it by converting to RDD and back again. Can you confirm that a UDF is required if using Dataframe API pls?

Comment: Yes.. there is performance hit when you use udf.. even if you convert it to RDD, you will be doing similar sort of scala collection functions and that too will have a hit.. I tried my best to not to use UDF, but couldn't.. the slice function in 2.4 allows only literals in 2nd and 3rd parameter.. not other columns.. otherwise this could have been solved without udfs.. im hoping that next spark version will have that feature..

Comment: @stack0114106  Posted

Comment: Interested in your critical appraisal. I am going to check what DS could mean.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach not using UDF is as follows - note sliding can be used as well, but it does involve a conversion to RDD and back again:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

// No use of UDF means conversion to RDD and back again.
val data = List( (102, Array("a", "b", "c")), (103, Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8")), (104, Array("r"))  )
val rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
val df = rdd.toDF("k", "v")

// Make groups of 3 as requested, methods possible. 
val rddX = df.as[(Int, List[String])].rdd // This avoids Row and Any issues that typically crop up.
//val rddY = rddX.map(x => (x._1, x._2.grouped(3).toArray)) 
val rddY = rddX.map(x => (x._1, x._2.sliding(3,3).toArray)) 

// Get k,v's with v the set of 3 and make single columns.
val df2 = rddY.toDF("k", "v")
val df3 = df2.select($"k", explode($"v").as("v_3"))
val df4 = df3.select($"k", $"v_3"(0).as("v_3_1"), $"v_3"(1).as("v_3_2"), $"v_3"(2).as("v_3_3") )
df4.show(false)
```

returns:

```
+---+-----+-----+-----+
|k  |v_3_1|v_3_2|v_3_3|
+---+-----+-----+-----+
|102|a    |b    |c    |
|103|1    |2    |3    |
|103|4    |5    |6    |
|103|7    |8    |null |
|104|r    |null |null |
+---+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: great!.. the spark analyzer will not be able to optimize that goes into the map() function..in a way that's what the UDF does it my answer.. so both created analysis barrier.. the advantage of UDF is that it can be reused.. and shared across projects.. whereas rdd.map doesn't ..

Comment: True on reuse for sure. I have to get my head around it, the explode is followed by grouped 3 that is the clue. Learnsome,

Comment: Another advantage is that udfs can be registered in spark catalog.. which can be reused when you use sql.. https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-scala.html

Comment: Sure, aware of that, but got into inline habits! Serialkization etc. etc. contributes to that.

Answer (score 0):

there is probably a better solution, but I came up with this:

```
import java.util.Arrays
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val employees = Array((101,Array("a","b","c","d","e")),(102,Array("q","w","e")),(103,Array("z","x","w","t","e","q","s")))
def f(emp:Int, num:Array[String]):Row={
  Row.fromSeq(s"${emp}" +: num)
}
val rowArray =for {
  x <- employees
  z <- x._2.sliding(3,3)
}yield f(x._1,Arrays.copyOf(z,3))

import spark.implicits._

val schema = StructType(
  List(StructField("emp", StringType, false),
    StructField("col1", StringType, true),
    StructField("col2", StringType, true),
    StructField("col3", StringType, true)))

val sqlContext=new SQLContext(sc)

val dfFromArray = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(rowArray), schema)
dfFromArray.show
```

It will return you something like this:

```
+---+----+----+----+                                                            
|emp|col1|col2|col3|
+---+----+----+----+
|101|   a|   b|   c|
|101|   d|   e|null|
|102|   q|   w|   e|
|103|   z|   x|   w|
|103|   t|   e|   q|
|103|   s|null|null|
+---+----+----+----+
```

Comment: But what if this is a column of a Data Array in first instance?

Comment: I like the logic but what if from a Data Frame as input?

Comment: I have an alternative solution that I will post later.

Comment: The input is a Data Frame. If i'm converting that to RDD , WrappedArray is formed. Also I have list like [ a12, ab b12, c12]. sliding is not woking on array[any]

Comment: Any is always an issue with Spark Scala I have found. Type erasure etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer that I should have posted, if not using a UDF.

Here we use the newer **Dataset** which allows us to use Scala functions directly on DS-fields easier, like an RDD. **That's the point here**.

Indeed DS's are best of both worlds and point taken that a UDF is not used as in other answer, but sometimes the performance is an issue.

In any event, same results gotten so only DS approach shown. Note that DS and DF definitions change - these are indicated in the val names.

```
case class X(k: Integer, v: List[String]) 

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq(  (102, Array("a", "b", "c")),
               (103, Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8")), 
               (104, Array("r"))  ).toDF("k", "v")
val ds = df.as[X]
val df2 = ds.map(x => (x.k, x.v.sliding(3,3).toArray))
            .withColumnRenamed ("_1", "k" )
            .withColumnRenamed ("_2", "v") 
val df3 = df2.select($"k", explode($"v").as("v_3")).select($"k", $"v_3"(0).as("v_3_1"),
                     $"v_3"(1).as("v_3_2"), $"v_3"(2).as("v_3_3") )

df3.show(false)
```

results again in:

```
+---+-----+-----+-----+
|k  |v_3_1|v_3_2|v_3_3|
+---+-----+-----+-----+
|102|a    |b    |c    |
|103|1    |2    |3    |
|103|4    |5    |6    |
|103|7    |8    |null |
|104|r    |null |null |
+---+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: @stack0114106  Posted another DS based answer.